# how to update the transaction status based on payments and due_on transaction in Laravel 9 + API

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a transaction and payments system. I want to update the status of transactions according to payments and transaction history, for example

The status becomes paid in the event that the full amount has been paid and before the date of creating the transaction due on

The status becomes overdue if the payment is late and the payment has not been made

The status becomes outstanding if the amount is not completed but the due date for payment has not been exceeded

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('payer_id');
            $table->decimal('amount', 8, 2);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('subcategory_id');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->date('due_on');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('transaction_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('buyer_id');
            $table->decimal('amount', 8, 2);
            $table->string('payment_method');
            $table->date('paid_at');
            $table->string('details');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'payer_id',
        'category_id',
        'subcategory_id',
        'amount',
        'status',
        'due_on'
    ];

    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'payer_id', 'id');
    }

    public function payments(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payment::class);
    }
```

```
class Payment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable =[
        'transaction_id'   ,
        'buyer_id',
        'amount'        ,
        'payment_method',
        'paid_at'       ,
        'details'       ,
    ];

    public function transaction(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Transaction::class,'transaction_id');
    }

public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'buyer_id', 'id');
}
}
```

what I must to do and solve this problem
note that I create this SQL query was worked but I don't have idea how use it in Laravel

```
SELECT 
 case 
     when  (sum(p.amount) < t.amount)  AND  t.due_on <  NOW() then 'Overdue'
     when  (sum(p.amount) <= t.amount) AND t.due_on > NOW() then 'Outstanding'  
          ELSE 'paid'
    END AS status  
FROM 
  transactions t
    JOIN 
   payments p ON t.id = p.transaction_id
WHERE t.id = 2 AND p.buyer_id = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solution it's worked with me

```
public function show(Transaction $transaction)
    {
        $status = DB::table('transactions as t')
            ->select(DB::raw("case
         when  (sum(p.amount) < t.amount) AND t.due_on < now() then 'Overdue'
         when  (sum(p.amount) < t.amount) AND t.due_on > now() then 'Outstanding'
             ELSE 'paid'
                END AS status"))
            ->join('payments as p', 't.id', '=', 'p.transaction_id')
            ->where('t.id', '=', $transaction->id)
            ->where('p.buyer_id', '=', Auth::id())
            ->groupBy('t.id')
            ->get();
        return $status;
    }
```